# Details of $z=u \cos(v) \sin(u), u=e^{xy^2}, v=x^2+y \quad \frac {\partial z} {\partial x}=?,\frac {\partial z} {\partial y}=?$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given
$$z=u \cos(v) \sin(u), \quad u=e^{xy^2}, \quad v=x^2+y$$
How to show details of finding $\dfrac {\partial z} {\partial x}$ and $\dfrac {\partial z} {\partial y}$?

Comment: What are the A's to which you refer? Do you mean the partial derivatives $\partial$? Also, please share your thoughts on the problem: What do you get when you try the derivative?

Comment: yes.I didn't know how to write that.

Comment: I've edited your post to include math formatting. Please verify that it says what you intended; please also explain what you've tried: For example, do you know the statement of the chain rule in this context?

Comment: Try logging the expression first, because differentiating a sum is easier than differentiating a product.

Comment: az/ax=az/au*au/ax+az/av*av/ax,

Comment: what does 'logging the expression' mean?

Comment: Take log and remember that $\frac{d \log f(x)}{dx}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$

Comment: Does anyone know how to differentiate using the chain rule? Yes, this is a math site. Can you do my history homework for me please?

Comment: I don't know that taking log z would be very helpful in this case since it would require an additional chain rule step to be implemented with log(cos(v)) and log(sin(u)).

Comment: @dfeuer : if your history homework is about effects of French revolution on mathematical analysis, then look up Cauchy's life after French revolution. :)

Comment: @Arjang Please don't edit titles to make them consist of just symbols, or be less descriptive. I've noticed you doing this on other questions, too. Please stop.

Comment: @Potato: I try to make them to be to the point, with least amount of characters. But if you can point me to an instance of making them being less descriptive would be good, as I strive to make the titles as descriptive as possible without needing them read the content. What is the issue with titles consisting of just symbols? I have seen many math articles with titles consisting of just symbols for their title. But I do what I can to keep as much as possible people happy.

Comment: @Arjang You've changed titles about certain integrals to consist of just the integral, without any words (e.g. evaluate). There are many things you one could want to do with integrals (prove they converge, find asymptotics, etc), so having the title just be symbols is undesirable. More importantly, having symbol-only titles is bad for technical reasons (you can't right-click them).

Comment: @Potato : that is the perfect reason. Regarding not being able to click the links, is it a technical issue that has been passed on to the SE techs? I too want to see the limit of 150 chars to be lifted from math SE.

Comment: @Arjang I am not sure. Right-clicking on symbols has special TeX-only purposes (changing renderers, for example). Regardless, thanks for listening to my unsolicited suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

Another hint:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Answer (score 1):

#### Hint

$$\frac{\partial z}{ \partial x} = \frac{\partial z }{ \partial u }\frac{\partial u }{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z }{ \partial v }\frac{\partial v }{\partial x}$$
$$\frac{\partial z }{ \partial y} = \frac{\partial z }{ \partial u} \frac{\partial u }{ \partial y}+\frac{\partial z }{ \partial v} \frac{\partial v }{ \partial y}$$

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$?

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote in the comments: $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
So find each partial derivative separately and then combine everything:

$\begin{align}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}= \frac{\partial}{\partial u}(u \cos(v) \sin(u)) = \cos(v)\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(u \sin(u))\right] = \cos(v)[1\sin(u) + u\cos(u)]\\
&\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(e^{xy^2}) = y^2e^{xy^2}\end{align}$

(Some extra explanation for above: for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$, you can take $\cos(v)$ out front because you are only finding the derivative with respect to $u$. Thus any function of $v$ can be treated like a constant and factored out in front of the partial derivative. Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(u \sin(u))$ was determined with product rule and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(e^{xy^2})$ was determined with chain rule.)

$\begin{align}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}= \frac{\partial}{\partial v}(u \cos(v) \sin(u)) = u\sin(u)\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial v}(\cos(v))\right] = u\sin(u)[-\sin(v)] = -u\sin(u)\sin(v)\\
&\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+y) = 2x\end{align}$

Then put everything together:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = (\cos(v)[1\sin(u) + u\cos(u)])(y^2e^{xy^2}) -u\sin(u)\sin(v)(2x )$$

Now try to find $\partial z/\partial y$ for yourself.

Comment: I think you may have a minor error here, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 2x$, not $2x + y$.

Comment: @GregE. Ooops ya. Edited. Thank you.